# Trigger an event in GTM if the user is logged in?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I’m trying to trigger a tag (a button click) only when a user is logged in. So, if the user clicks the “write a review” button the event will trigger if the user is logged in, otherwise it won’t trigger.

In the source code log in data is indicated by this string:

`<input type="hidden" id="isLoged" name="isLoged" value=“true”>`

If the user is logged in the value return “**true**”, if not it returns “**false**”.

I’ve searched the web, tried many things but couldn’t find a way to do it.

Thanks in advance any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a Custom JS variable:

```
function () {
    return document.getElementById("isLoged").value;
}
```